# Apache server takes 20s to load over HTTPS, but fast over HTTP

Tags: centos, ssl, apache-2.4, https

I rented a new dedicated server (Apache 2.4, CentOs 6.9) and I cannot figure why pages with HTTPS are taking forever to load while HTTP loads normally. You can test one of the sites here: https://www.dailywritingtips.com/

Clues so far:

- Restarting the server solves the problem for a while, but after
  some time it comes back.
- cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail gives numbers between 100 and 200. The tech support said that this is not the cause of the problem
- They disabled OCSP stapling saying there was a bug there, but it didn't solve the problem.
- The problem appears on all websites on the server.
- Apache config values (i.e. maxrequestworkers) are all set to default values

I have an strace.log file, but it is huge. I can post specific parts if that will help, or get other logs.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1**

SSL Status from WHM below:

```
SSL/TLS Session Cache Status:
cache type: SHMCB, shared memory: 1024000 bytes, current entries: 145
subcaches: 32, indexes per subcache: 177
time left on oldest entries' objects: avg: 68 seconds, (range: 4...261)
index usage: 2%, cache usage: 3%
total entries stored since starting: 1888
total entries replaced since starting: 0
total entries expired since starting: 1743
total (pre-expiry) entries scrolled out of the cache: 0
total retrieves since starting: 2421 hit, 5695 miss
total removes since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
```

**Update 2 - Possible Solution**

Apparently the certificate was for TSL 1.2 but the server didn't have it installed. Installing it seem to have solved the issue.

Comment: Any clues perhaps in the mod_ssl output in the mod_status output?

Comment: @user188737 how do I get those?

Comment: SSL/TLS cache is not a problem. I once had a problem with mod_itk where it connected but did not close properly, leading to a 10 second timeout. You could try the php and curl commands in the bug decription to see if there is a "closing" problem here. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpm-itk/+bug/1504162 I think you should also capture a network dump. You can do tcpdump -D first to see the numbers assigned to the interfaces.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem neither using Chrome nor Firefox on Linux. This site loads within a few seconds.

Comment: Maybe a client side problem with antivirus or some such programs?

Comment: It looks like we solved it. Apparently the cert was for TSL 1.2 but the server didn't have it installed.

Comment: Certs do not care about the TLS level as such. I suspect that the problem was not actually in the webserver but may have been slow responses from the certificate authority servers when the browser checks the validity.

Comment: Disabling OCSP Stapling is a bad idea. This causes the clients to issue requests to the CA to validate your certificate. This can slow down the first page load. If your vendor has this bug, switch vendors or operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

## View SSL data in the status module:

```
    <Location /server-status>
            SetHandler server-status
            Require local
            #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
    </Location>

    # Keep track of extended status information for each request
    ExtendedStatus On
```

`curl -s http://127.0.0.1/server-status | lynx -stdin`

Example

```
   SSL/TLS Session Cache Status:
   cache type: SHMCB, shared memory: 2097152 bytes, current entries: 7204
   subcaches: 64, indexes per subcache: 182
   time left on oldest entries' objects: avg: 184 seconds, (range: 15...640)
   index usage: 61%, cache usage: 80%
   total entries stored since starting: 14566
   total entries replaced since starting: 0
   total entries expired since starting: 2085
   total (pre-expiry) entries scrolled out of the cache: 5277
   total retrieves since starting: 1560890 hit, 1298 miss
   total removes since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
```

## Capture a network trace to analyze in Wireshark

`tcpdump -i1 -s0 -w /my/outputfile host my.ip.add.dres and port 443`